# Different Sidebar with WP-Ecommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, e-commerce, sidebar

I have a blog with wp-ecommerce, now what i would like to do is use a seperate sidebar to the shop pages but WP-Ecommerce seems to pull your template sidebar and can't find how to specify the sidebar to use.

I have created a new sidebar in my functions.php just don't know where to call it...

Any help much appreciated

Thanks
Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
As you have created a separate sidebar, now you must be seeing that in your admin panel.

So just add the widgets you want to appear in the sidebar.

Next go to your sidebar.php page, there you cana put a condition i.e. for the products page

If your products page is a separate template then use the name of the file i.e.

if ( is_page_template('product.php') ) {
    register_sidebr('name of the sidebar');
} else {
    register_sidebr('name of the sidebar');
}
```

Comment: woulde there be a way to make it apply to all the WP Ecommerce pages or would i just use seperate if statement for each page :) Thanks

Comment: The above code works for a speicific template, do you want separate sidebar for each page??

Comment: No just 2 sidebars one for main part of site then one for shop part (Product page, single product page, category page and cart page) tried adding this code also but now no sidebar showing anywhere :(

Comment: Here is sample code for a specific sidebar in home page and another sidebar for all other pages

<?php if(is_front_page()) { ?>
<div id="primary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
    
      <ul class="xoxo">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'Primary Widget Area - Sidebar 1' ); ?>
   </ul>
            </div>
            <?php } else { ?>
   <div id="primary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
    
      <ul class="xoxo">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'Secondary Widget Area - Sidebar 1' ); ?>
   </ul>
            </div>
<?php } ?>

Comment: then do one thing just mention the template names in the like this is_page_template('your page name')

Comment: Ok that works but its not just front page either its like all pages/posts primary sidebar all shop pages shop sidebar is that possible, thanks for your help so far :)

Comment: if ( is_page() ) {
    register_sidebr('name of the sidebar');
} elseif  (is_page_template('product.php')){
    register_sidebr('name of the sidebar');
}